# Adding left and right images programatically to UIButton

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add an image to the left and right of a UIButton.  I've researched and whilst there are many solutions, I haven't been able to get any to work for me.

I need to be able to:

1. Show or hide one or both icons
2. Customize the color of the icons based on other logic elsewhere
3. have the content centered

Layout is: 
OUTTER PADDING + LEFT ICON + INSIDE PADDING + LABEL + PADDING + RIGHT ICON + RIGHT PADDING

[image]

This is the closest I've come but doens't tick all the boxes.  I have the following code as an extension on UIButton:

```
func leftImage(image: UIImage, padding: CGFloat, renderMode: UIImage.RenderingMode) {
    self.setImage(image.withRenderingMode(renderMode), for: .normal)
    contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    let availableSpace = bounds.inset(by: contentEdgeInsets)
    let availableWidth = availableSpace.width - imageEdgeInsets.right - (imageView?.frame.width ?? 0) - (titleLabel?.frame.width ?? 0)
    titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: availableWidth / 2, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: padding, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

func rightImage(image: UIImage, padding: CGFloat, renderMode: UIImage.RenderingMode){
    self.setImage(image.withRenderingMode(renderMode), for: .normal)
    semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    contentHorizontalAlignment = .center
    let availableSpace = bounds.inset(by: contentEdgeInsets)
    let availableWidth = availableSpace.width - imageEdgeInsets.left - (imageView?.frame.width ?? 0) - (titleLabel?.frame.width ?? 0)
    titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: availableWidth / 2)
    imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: padding)
}
```

Currently, the problems I have with this code are:
1. can't change the icon colors outside of the tint style
2. rendering isn't laying out correctly
3. I can only get the left or the right icon to show but not both

If I call the leftImage method, I get this result:

[image]

If I call the rightImage method, I get this result:

[image]

And if I call both, I get this:

[image]

I apologize in advance if this isn't clear, I'm still new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed advise from @matt and have the following code:

```
        // LEFT IMAGE
        let newLeftItemToAdd = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "star"))
        myButton.addSubview(newLeftItemToAdd)

        //Sizing
        newLeftItemToAdd.width(20)
        newLeftItemToAdd.height(20)

        //Vertical positioning
        newLeftItemToAdd.centerYToSuperview()

        //Horizontal positioning
        let padding = 10.0
        newLeftItemToAdd.rightToLeft(of: myButton.titleLabel!, offset: CGFloat(-padding), isActive: true)

        //Change color
        newLeftItemToAdd.setImageColor(color: .green)

        // RIGHT IMAGE
        let newRightItemToAdd = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "star"))
        myButton.addSubview(newRightItemToAdd)

        //Sizing
        newRightItemToAdd.width(20)
        newRightItemToAdd.height(20)

        //Vertical positioning
        newRightItemToAdd.centerYToSuperview()

        //Horizontal positioning
        newRightItemToAdd.leftToRight(of: myButton.titleLabel!, offset: CGFloat(padding), isActive: true)

        //Change color
        newRightItemToAdd.setImageColor(color: .orange)
```

This works perfectly now and gives the flexibility to change colors of each icon individually if I need it.

I also created an extension of UIImageview to provide further flexibility:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func setImageColor(color: UIColor) {
        let templateImage = self.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.image = templateImage
        self.tintColor = color
    }
}
```

And this is the end result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> 1. can't change the icon colors outside of the tint style 2. rendering isn't laying out correctly 3. I can only get the left or the right icon to show but not both

Well, 1 is because you didn't specify that you want this image's rendering mode should be `.alwaysOriginal`. And 3 is because a button only has one image.

And 2 is because what you're trying to do is hard, because you're trying to make the framework do something it doesn't want to do.

If I were you, I'd give up trying to make the icons *part* of the button and just make a row of icon-button-icon as three separate views. If you *really* want to make this all one button, you'll have to use the button's background image, drawing it in real time to the correct size so as to contain the desired icons.

Comment: Thanks.  Re the color - I was trying to set this programmatically without having to have a number of different images.

I think you're right about the icon + button + icon option.  I did try that earlier but couldn't line up the content and gave up as I thought I was going down the wrong track but will try again.

Comment: Well, again, if this is just a pair of image views, you can continue using the tint color and give each of those image views a tint color different from the button's tint colot.

Comment: Thanks.  Have followed your advise and just added to images as subviews.